# bokeh - setting number of decimal places on axis

Tags: bokeh

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html
I have found the 'precision' property and it looks like this is what I want to use. I have a figure `p` and am trying to set the axes labels to show a specific number of decimal places. Currently, the labels look like:

1.949, 1.95, 1.951, 1.952, 1.953

But I want:

1.949, 1.950, 1.951, 1.952, 1.953

How do I actually implement this precision property to my axis label to change it?

For example, I have tried `p.models.formatters.TickFormatter.precision = 3'

And playing around with the terms after "p." but it keeps giving:

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'models'

The documentation on the website is confusing to me. What line do I put in my code to use this 'precision' property?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter

p.xaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.000")
```

The code for which is taken nearly verbatim from the User's Guide section on [Tick Label Formats](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-formats)

> The documentation on the website is confusing to me.

As a gentle aside, comments like this are frustrating to maintainers, because they are not actionable. There are lots of docs resources, which specific ones did you find or try to use and have problems with? What  exactly did you try searching for that *didn't* lead you to e.g. the link above? Even if we wanted to consider trying to make some or other improvement based on your experience, there is not enough information provided in statements like this to be able to do anything.

Comment: It is confusing to me because in the documentation link I sent (bokeh.pydata.org), which is often the first Google search result for questions involving Bokeh, it is not clear how to actually implement the code. For example, I would have never guessed I had to use the syntax that you provided in your answer, and there is nothing suggesting that on that documentation link. In retrospect, I was looking at the wrong page, and should have found the user guide that you linked to. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately we don't have much control over how Google indexes our site. If we did, I would not have it send people to the reference guide first, for sure. In general reference guides do not cover the "how" they cover the "these are the details" for things you already have some familiarity with how to use. If you are looking for "getting started" type information and find yourself looking at a reference guide, it's probably a good idea to back up and see if there are tutorials or user's guides available, instead.

Comment: I guess I would also add: The Project Discourse is a good place to go for support besides SO and has a sophisticated search that covers many years of Bokeh-specific discussions. https://discourse.bokeh.org